# Add free month to Authorize.net ARB Subscription

Tags: php, authorize.net, recurring-billing

One of my clients offered a free month added to a customer's ongoing subscription. As far as I can see in the ARB documentation [here](http://developer.authorize.net/api/reference/features/recurring_billing.html), I don't think there's a good way to do it. There is also no apparent way to do it when logged into the Authorize.Net platform.

The only good option I see to achieve this is to delete the subscription and create a new one.  We do not store the user's full credit card information on our servers; I have no way to do it without the user's intervention, which isn't appropriate.

This seems like it would be a fairly common use case, so I was wondering if you had any insights in how to do it that I may be missing?

Comment: You're right, you can't randomly throw a free payment into an ongoing subscription. You either have to cancel it and start it again when payments  are to resume or refund your users for that month (which is not an attractive option). Next time have them confer with you before doing things their website doesn't support. Good luck.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The best options for you would be to either refund the transaction for the month that is free, delete the subscription and create a new one manually, or use an existing third party web application or subscription manager which has the capability to automatically delete and re-add a subscription.